# I can connect an application to 2 databases in Django?

Tags: python, django, oracle

I have a web application in Python django. I need to import users and display data about them from another database, from another existing application. All I need is the user to be able to login and display information about them. What solutions are?

Answer (score 4):

You can set 2 `DATABASES` in `settings.py`.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
    },
    'user_data': {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in one database store `User` models with authentication and stuff, in another rest information. You can connect information about specific `User` with a field that is storing `id` of `User` from another database.

If you have multiple databases and create a `model`, you should declare on which `db` it is going to be stored. If you didn't, it will be in `default` one (if you have it declared).

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'default'

class UserDataModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_data'
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer from @NixonSparrow was wrong.

`_meta.db_table` defined only table_name in database and not the database self.

for switch database you can use `manager.using('database_name')`, for every model, it is good declared here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing

in my project i use multiple router.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing

it help don't override every manager with using. But in your case:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
    },
    'other_users_data': {
        ...
    }
}
```

and somethere in views:

```
other_users = otherUserModel.objects.using('other_users_data')
```

Probably, `otherUserModel` should define in `meta`, which table you want to use `db_table = 'other_users_table_name'` and also probably it should have `managed=False`, to hide this model from migration manager.